# Embedded iframe from Tumblr can't load images automatically (URL not found)

Tags: iframe, tumblr

So I have twisted my head around this for a while now, and just got desperate after a longer period of anger.

My iframe loads and all, but the images' URL's is not found.
- BUT! If you click on the name of the guy's blog (Magnus Bjørnerud) the images suddenly loads, and all works fine, even when you refresh.  But not the first time.  Weird?!

http://www.fredberentsen.com/mbfoto/pages/blogg.html

That is the page where the blog is going to be loaded, it is a simple iframe with a link to the blog.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the iframe src is set to `http://mbfoto.tumblr.com/%E2%80%9D%3E%3C` which causes an error. If you change the src to `http://mbfoto.tumblr.com/` it should work.

Comment: That is strange indeed...  The original code was as the latter you wrote, but somehow something messed up.. Well, I rewrote the code only - and it seems to work..  Thank you :-)